# Linq to sql .Dynamic Where: string with System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: No property or field '0' exists in type 'myTable'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a dynamic query to one of myTables

For that I'm usin the following function:

```
public async Task<bool> search(DBContext db, M model, string uniqueNonIDField)
        {


            Type modelType = model.GetType();//get model of generic

            object modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);

            PropertyInfo field = modelType.GetProperty(uniqueNonIDField); //get property to get existing value


            if (field == null)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Campo {0} Não encontrado", uniqueNonIDField));

            string value = (string)field.GetValue(model, null); //get value to search in myTable


            field.SetValue(model, Regex.Replace(value, @"[\u002D\u2010\u2012\u2013\u2014]", "-"), null); //do some clean up

            value = (string)field.GetValue(model, null); //get new value after being cleaned


            if (db.Set(modelType).Where(String.Format("@0=@1", uniqueNonIDField, value)).Count() == 0) //Test if there is already any object in myTable with that value.
            {...do stuff}

...
}
```

But there is an error:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: No property or field '0' exists in type 'myTable'
```

If I hardcode all expression like:

```
if (db.myTable.Where("existingField=123").Count() == 0){...}
```

the error persist with:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: No property or field '123' exists in type 'myTable'
```

I'm trying to do as exemplified in many examples and saw many other stackoverflow similar answers, but can't find the reason for the error. Rookie mistake probably.

Can you please help me finding it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string to the where statement. `System.Linq.Dynamic` allows you to filter by string.

Everything seems to be okay in your code and maybe your issue is related to this one:
https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues/101

Are you using this code under dotnetcore? If yes then please install the related NuGet package and change the using to `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot pass your `where` statement as a string like this: `Where("existingField=123")`, you do it as an expression `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate`. In order to pass that expression you will have to know the type for which you want to filter

EDIT: Sample `Where`
Lets say you have `MyClass` in your `DbContext` like this:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
    }
```

Then to filter on the `Name` or `Id` property of `MyClass`, all you do is:

```
var filteredEntities = dbContext.MyClass.Where(x => x.Name == "test").ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please post an example?

Comment: I didn't give the downvote, but the code really doesn't answer the question... it was a better answer before the edit :)  however, "Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate" indicated me the path for a solution. When its fully implemented I'll insert it here.